# added a pipeline and now my terrain is pink...how do I fix it?

Tags: unity

I needed to add a pipeline to my world because an asset required it.  I was following the [directions here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@4.10/manual/index.html).

Since adding the pipeline, my terrain is pink.
[image]

I found a [references](https://forum.unity.com/threads/pink-terrain-with-rendered-pipeline.522920/) that stated the pipelines do not support terrain, there are problems with more than 4 textures (I have 1) etc...but this was a year ago.

Is this fixable or am I at choice between no pipeline or buying pipeline enabled terrain (and hence redoing all of my scenes)?

What is the solution?
Thnx
Matt

Comment: You'll need a terrain material that's compatible with the rendering pipeline you've chosen.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks.  that makes sense. any chance you might have link that helps me create that?

Comment: @DMGregory I looked on unity assets and am a bit confused how I determine if a material is compatible. I feel a little over my head atm.  thanks :)